# Remove Checkout System in WooCommerce - Make Downloads Freely Available

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the checkout system from my Wordpress website.

I am using WooCommerce & the Storefront Theme.

I have added WooCommerce for all the functionality of displaying products and adding them to cart. But in the cart it needs to be just be a series of downloads.

Using the https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bulk-download/ I have managed to create products as downloads and have the functionality - but all this occurs after checkout and confirmation of order. I need to remove the checkout entirely. When the user clicks to go to their cart they need to be taken to their downloads which immediately appear and don't need to be paid for.

This doesn't quite cover it. https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-simplify-free-woocommerce-checkout/ The whole process needs to stop sooner than this.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching it wrong. Rather than stopping the process early, maybe you need to complete it automatically for them and bypass it. That way WooCommerce can do it's thing and you make sure all of your data is in place.

Comment: Just to clarify, to the user, it would look like the process ends there, but it really wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. I am working on this using a plugin which automatically completes the order but I am still struggling in bypassing all of the steps. And instead of taking you to a checkout page and confirming the order. Having the order complete without even needing to click through any of the steps and taking them straight to the downloads page.

Comment: Glad that helps.